# Wrong resolution on android device for view

Tags: android, xamarin, screen-resolution

I have a problem on my Samsung Galaxy A5. My OpenGL application is displayed in a different (lower) resolution. The actual resolution is 1080x1920 but it gets rendered in 810x1440 and then scaled up to the full resolution, which makes it look bad. I remember that it was fine in the beginning and I didn't knowingly change anything but it suddenly used another resolution.

Here are the display metrics:

```
{DisplayMetrics{density=2.25, width=810, height=1440, scaledDensity=2.25, xdpi=317.0, ydpi=318.0}}
    base: {Java.Lang.Object}
    Density: 2.25
    DensityDpi: Android.Util.DisplayMetricsDensity.D360
    HeightPixels: 1440
    JniPeerMembers: {Android.Runtime.XAPeerMembers}
    ScaledDensity: 2.25
    WidthPixels: 810
    Xdpi: 317
    Ydpi: 318
```

Does anyone know how I can control this behaviour?

Comment: I just started to note this behavior with a game I'm developing. The weird thing is, the development APK is rendered at the right resolution of 1080x1920, while the release one is rendered at 810x1440